# Synchronise DatePicker with an UIPickerView and use a Label to display the value selected from any of them

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I need a little bit help because I'm stuck with my homework.
I need to synchronise a PickerView with a DatePicker and also to show in a Label the value selected.
When I change values on DatePicker are not reflected on my PickerView.
Can anyone figure out why ?
Here is a picture to show you where I am for the moment and also my code:

[image: Screenshot]
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDate: UILabel!

    var days = [String]()
    var months = Array<String>()
    var years = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy"
        labelDate.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        // Arrays for Picker View
        days = Array(1...31).map({ String($0) })
        months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        years = Array(2000...2030).map({ String($0) })
    }

    // We set number of components in the Picker View (in our case 3 columns)
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    // Get the number of elements for each component (each column)
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        switch(component) {
        case 0: return months.count
        case 1: return days.count
        case 2: return years.count
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    // Our ViewController will adopt the protocol "UIPickerViewDelegate" and after we display data for each element on a new Row
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        switch(component) {
        case 0: return months[row]
        case 1: return days[row]
        case 2: return years[row]
        default: return nil
        }
    }

      // Select a date from PickerView and show it in the DatePicker and also in the Label
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let monthSelected = months[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        let daySelected = days[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
        let yearSelected = years[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]
        let dataString = "\(daySelected)/" + "\(monthSelected)/" + "\(yearSelected)"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dataString)
        datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: true)
        labelDate.text = "\(daySelected)/" + "\(monthSelected)/" + "\(yearSelected)"


        // Here I need the logic for February to have 28 days always or if I know
        // how to do, then to implement some Logic for Leap Years

        /*

         if(yearSelected % 4 == 0 && (yearSelected % 100 != 0) || (yearSelected % 400 == 0)){
         february will return 29 days
         } else{
         february will return 28 days }
         }

         */


    }

    // Select a date from DatePicker and show it in the UIPickerView and also in the Label
    @IBAction func dateSelectedFromDatePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year], from: self.datePicker.date)
        let day = components.day
        let month = components.month
        let year = components.year

       pickerView.selectRow(month!-1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
       pickerView.selectRow(day!-1, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
       pickerView.selectRow(year!-1, inComponent: 2, animated: true)

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy"
        labelDate.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance !!!

Comment: What's your question? You've posted some requirements and you've posted a bunch of code. But you have not explained what problem you are having. Please [edit] your question (don't post comments) and clearly explain what your issue is.

Comment: Your edit a start in the right direction. So what actually happens when you select a date in the date picker? Is your `dateSelectedFromDatePicker` called (I'm guessing it's hooked up to the "value changed" event but you don't tell us that)? Then what happens? Please provide specific details about what testing you've done and what happens exactly when the code runs.

Comment: As rmaddy says, you need to explain what's happening with the code you posted. Are you getting a crash? Are you sure your date picker's target method `dateSelectedFromDatePicker(_:)` is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

component  0 --> months

component  1 --> days

component  2 --> years

Change  This code  , make sure that  `day!-1` ,  `month!-1` , `year!-1`   represent correct index in arrays days, months,years

Here is code that should change:

```
    pickerView.selectRow(day!-1, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(month!-1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    pickerView.selectRow(year!-1, inComponent: 2, animated: true)
```

Comment: I changed the column index but the Year column is still not working. when I change the value in the DatePicker I don't get any value for year in the PickerView.

Comment: Yes print year  `year!-1`  , are it index or what or String  print it before animate and tell me what result

Comment: I think I need to do it using the DateFormatter() instead of Calendar().

And I done something like this but I don't know what to put for the first parameter for selectRow.
`let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()`
`dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy"`
`pickerView.selectRow( RowForSelectedDay ,   inComponent: 1, animated: true)`
`pickerView.selectRow( RowForSelectedMonth , inComponent: 0, animated: true)`
`pickerView.selectRow( RowForSelectedYear ,  inComponent: 2, animated: true)`